# Is there an equivalent to codehaus' plugin's <xsdPathWithinArtifact> for the maven-jaxb2-plugin?

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

jaxb2-maven-plugin has the `<xsdPathWithinArtifact>` [option](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.4/xjc-mojo.html#xsdPathWithinArtifact). Is there an equivalent in maven-jaxb2-plugin? What is the recommended way to include the schema file in the produced jar? I'm currently using Maven's native `<resources>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

No, there is no such option in [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and there will not be. Managing resources is not the concern of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin), there are other Maven plugins for that.

The *recommended way* is exactly what you're doing - place your schemas under `src/main/resources` and they will be packaged in the resulting JAR.

Comment: Thanks! Since you're the author, do you know how I would combine modular schema compilation with inline customization? I wrote up the issue I'm having here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686096/xjc-fails-on-imported-schema-when-using-episodes-due-to-property-customization. (I see that you actually edited a related question years ago.)